# Change PhoneGap FileSystem Root Path

Tags: cordova, marmalade

I'm wondering if there's any way to change PhoneGap's fileSystem object?

I'm currently using Web Marmalade (which includes a modified PhoneGap in it) and window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT...) returns "wm", rather than something like "/mnt/sdcard" on my Android phone. This causes problems because I can't write to /mnt/sdcard - there will be a security error, most probably because /mnt/sdcard is not part of the root filesystem "wm".

So I'm just wondering if there's an easy way to change this fileSystem?
I tried something like:

```
var root = new DirectoryEntry('myroot', '/mnt/sdcard');
var fileSystem = new FileSystem('myfs', root);
```

But that doesn't seem to help:

```
alert('fileSystem.root.fullPath: ' + fileSystem.root.fullPath);  //returns ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
var myRoot = null;
function myRoot() {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("/mnt/sdcard", function(dirEntry) {
      myRoot = dirEntry;
    });
}
```

to get a DirectoryEntry object that represents /mnt/sdcard and do you File API operations off of it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Simon. I've tried it and got the security error (FileError.SECURITY_ERR) that I was talking about...

Comment: Did you make sure you added the write external storage permission to your AndroidManifest.xml? Also, I have no idea what Web Marmalade is.

Comment: Yes the permission has been added during the test. I think this problem is specific to Web Marmalade. Marmalade is a cross-platform C++ app engine, and Web Marmalade is the version that integrates a modified version of PhoneGap in it for HTML5/JS/CSS3 development. Thanks for the replies though, Simon! I see your replies in a lot of other PhoneGap questions, that's very helpful.